# "Аккордеон" в "Аккордеоне" на js. Не jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите пожалуйста советом, как "научить" последний блок "Item 3" разворачиваться в ответ на разворачивание внутренних блоков и отображать их содержимое. Пример демонстрирующий ситуацию:

```js
var oMC_menu = document.getElementById('MC_menu'),
  mcMenuItems = oMC_menu.querySelectorAll('#MC_menu > ul > li > p');
var mcMenuClassItems = oMC_menu.querySelectorAll('#MC_menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > p');

for (let i = 0; i < mcMenuItems.length; i++) {
  mcMenuItems[i].onclick = function() {
    thisNode = this.parentNode.childNodes[2];
    if (thisNode.style.height === '0px' || thisNode.style.height === '') {
      SlideDown(thisNode, Number((getComputedStyle(thisNode).height).split('px')[0]), thisNode.scrollHeight);
      if (typeof mcMenuLastItem !== 'undefined' && mcMenuLastItem !== thisNode)
        SlideUp(mcMenuLastItem, Number((getComputedStyle(mcMenuLastItem).height).split('px')[0]));
      mcMenuLastItem = thisNode;
    } else {
      let heightBlock = Number((getComputedStyle(thisNode).height).split('px')[0]);
      console.log({
        bNode: thisNode,
        bHeight: heightBlock
      }, thisNode.scrollHeight);
      SlideUp(thisNode, heightBlock);
    }
  };
}
for (let i = 0; i < mcMenuClassItems.length; i++) {
  mcMenuClassItems[i].onclick = function() {
    thisNode = this.parentNode.childNodes[2];
    if (thisNode.style.height === '0px' || thisNode.style.height === '') {
      SlideDown(thisNode, Number((getComputedStyle(thisNode).height).split('px')[0]), thisNode.scrollHeight);
      if (typeof mcMenuClassLastItem !== 'undefined' && mcMenuClassLastItem !== thisNode)
        SlideUp(mcMenuClassLastItem, Number((getComputedStyle(mcMenuClassLastItem).height).split('px')[0]));
      mcMenuClassLastItem = thisNode;
    } else {
      let heightBlock = Number((getComputedStyle(thisNode).height).split('px')[0]);
      console.log({
        bNode: thisNode,
        bHeight: heightBlock
      }, thisNode.scrollHeight);
      SlideUp(thisNode, heightBlock);
    }
  };
}

function SlideUp(block, heightBlock) {
  if (heightBlock > 0) {
    let step = 30,
      newHeight;
    step = SetStep(heightBlock, step);
    newHeight = (heightBlock - step < 0) ? 0 : heightBlock - step;
    block.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
    setTimeout(SlideUp, 10, block, newHeight);
  }
}

function SlideDown(block, heightBlock, newHeight) {
  if (heightBlock < newHeight) {
    let step = 30;
    step = SetStep(newHeight - heightBlock, step);
    heightBlock = (heightBlock + step >= newHeight) ? newHeight : heightBlock + step;
    block.style.height = heightBlock + 'px';
    setTimeout(SlideDown, 10, block, heightBlock, newHeight);
  }
}
let mapStep = new Map([
  [0, 1],
  [10, 2],
  [20, 3],
  [30, 4],
  [40, 5],
  [50, 6],
  [60, 7],
  [70, 8],
  [80, 9],
  [90, 10],
  [100, 11]
]);

function SetStep(interval, mStep) {
  let i;
  return mapStep.has(i = ((interval / 10) >> 0) * 10) ? mapStep.get(i) : mStep;
}
```

```css
#MC_menu {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(98, 49, 35, 0.5);
  border: solid #b56b2b 3px;
  min-width: calc(335px + 30px);
}

#MC_menu li {
  list-style: none;
}

#MC_menu>ul>li>p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#MC_menu ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#MC_menu>ul>li>p:hover {
  background: rgba(181, 107, 43, 0.6);
}

#MC_menu>ul>li>div {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

#MC_menu>ul>li>div>ul>li {
  border: solid red 1px;
  text-indent: 0;
}

#MC_menu>ul>li>div>ul>li>div {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  text-indent: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

#MC_menu>ul>li>div>ul>li>p {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#MC_menu>ul>li>div>ul>li>p:hover {
  background-color: rgba(156, 30, 26, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div id="MC_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><p>Item 1</p>
            <div>text.<br><br>Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста.
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><p>item 2</p>
            <div>text.<br><br>Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста. Много много много текста для теста.
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><p>Item 3</p>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><p>Item 3_1</p>
                        <div>
                            Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><p>Item 3_2</p>
                        <div>
                            Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text<br>Text
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: А чем `jQuery` не угодил? ведь он специально был создан для подобного, а еще он до безобразия упрощает работу с `DOM`. + он максимально кроссбраузерный. да и код выглядит в разы понятнее и красивее...Одни плюсы, а вы вот так вот пищите костыли...

Comment: Вероятно, в сущности этой попытки кроется контекст не относящийся к Вашему вопросу, но его легко уловить, если у Вас такой профессиональный взгляд на подобные вещи - я учусь. Мне интересно узнать концепцию js, прежде чем переходить к пользованию фреймворков, делающих бестолкового кодера ещё и ленивым. Поэтому, спотыкание о такие банальные вещи мне видится бОльшим лекарством.

Касаемо же вопроса, решил ситуацию так, что раз у меня всегда имеется ссылка на предыдущий нод, то изменение его высоты и есть решение, а уровень вложенности регулирую передачей в функцию массива используемых нодов.